# Set what can be selected by the datacursor in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a `plot` and a `scatter3` in the same figure in Matlab. The `plot`is just used as a "decoration", while the `scatter3`contains the actual data. But when I click on a data point to see its value, it often sticks to an element of the `plot` instead.

Is there a way to set that the data cursor can only stick to elements drawn by `scatter3` but not by plot?

Something like:

```
plot(..., dataCursorCanNotStick)
hold on
scatter3(..., dataCursorCanStick)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `set(plot_handle,'hittest','off')` for the `plot` you want to ignore when using the data cursor.

**Example:**

```
figure;
x = -10:0.01:10;
hold on;
h1 = plot(x,sin(x), 'r');
h2 = plot(x,cos(x), 'b');
set(h2,'hittest','off')
hold off;
```

when clicking on the blue plot, the data cursor will **not** snap to it.

[image]